# how to replace logo in webgoat 7.x?

Tags: css

I downloaded this JAR file:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/webgoat-war/webgoat-container-7.0.1-war-exec.jar

and ran it with:

java -jar webgoat-container-7.0.1-war-exec.jar

And the question I have is how to replace logo in webgoat 7.x? I looked over all files inside jar file and didn't find any PNG or JPEG files.

Then I looked over source code, which is:

```
<!--logo start-->
                <div class="brand">
                    <a href="/WebGoat/start.mvc" class="logo"><span>Web</span>Goat</a>
                </div>
<!--logo end-->
```

and its not clear, how to replace logo, which is on the top left, please?

[webgoat logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiHty.png)

Comment: have you tried looking in the css file for `.logo`?